# AJAX JSON Post to PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm trying to post JSON String via AJAX to PHP, but all examples not work.
First of all I learn https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_php_db_post 
Then i write own code. But no one of my example code below not working. And return one result:

```
index.php:6:string '[object Object]' (length=15)
index.php:7:null
index.php:8:null
```

First variant:

```
<?php

    $JsonPost   = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if ($JsonPost != null) {
        var_dump($JsonPost);
        var_dump(json_decode($JsonPost, true));
        var_dump(json_decode($JsonPost));
    } else {
    ?>
    <html> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var RequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            RequestObject.open("POST", window.location.href, true)
            RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

            var SomeObject      = {};
            SomeObject.Field1   = 'lalala';
            SomeObject.Array1   = [
                'lala1', 'lala2'
            ];

            RequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (RequestObject.readyState == 4 && RequestObject.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;
                }
            };

            var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};
            RequestObject.send(JsonStr);
        </script>
    <body id="body"></body> 
    </html>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

Second variant:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['JsonPost'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['JsonPost']);
    var_dump(json_decode($_POST['JsonPost'], true));
    var_dump(json_decode($_POST['JsonPost']));
} else {
?>
<html> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var RequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        RequestObject.open("POST", window.location.href, true)
        RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');

        var SomeObject      = {};
        SomeObject.Field1   = 'lalala';
        SomeObject.Array1   = [
            'lala1', 'lala2'
        ];

        RequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (RequestObject.readyState == 4 && RequestObject.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;
            }
        };

        var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};
        RequestObject.send("JsonPost=" + JsonStr);
    </script>
<body id="body"></body> 
</html>
<?php 
}

?>
```

Please help. 
PHP Version 5.6.28 
XAMPP v3.2.2 on Windows 10 (64-bit) 
Browser Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

## UPDATED

Working Example.

```
<?php

$JsonPost   = file_get_contents('php://input');
if ($JsonPost != null) {
    var_dump($JsonPost);
    var_dump(json_decode($JsonPost, true));
    var_dump(json_decode($JsonPost));
} else {
    ?>
<html> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var RequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        RequestObject.open("POST", window.location.href, true)
        RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        var SomeObject      = {};
        SomeObject.Field1   = 'lalala';
        SomeObject.Array1   = [
            'lala1', 'lala2'
        ];

        RequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (RequestObject.readyState == 4 && RequestObject.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;
            }
        };

        //var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};
        var JsonStr = JSON.stringify(SomeObject);
        RequestObject.send(JsonStr);
    </script>
<body id="body"></body> 
</html>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Many thanks to all who answered.

Comment: Keep it simple and only do the needed things. For example you are stringify your json so `'application/json'` is not needed. Please test it with a simple version (like in the first link) again.

Comment: Also do test `RequestObject.send("JsonPost=" + JSON.stringify(SomeObject));`   in your second tryout. Because with the `{` at the `var JsonStr = {` you are creating an real json object again.

Comment: what is expected result ?

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered.
The decision was very simple, and I was not attentive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};
> RequestObject.send(JsonStr);
> ```

Here you are:

1. Creating some JSON
2. Setting the JSON as the value of an object property
3. Implicitly converting the object to a string (which will be `"[object Object]"`)
4. Sending that string as the request body

But since you are trying to post JSON you should skip steps 2 and 3 … **just** pass the JSON:

```
RequestObject.send(JSON.stringify(SomeObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in you *Second variant* this:

```
    var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};
    RequestObject.send("JsonPost=" + JsonStr);
```

to

```
    RequestObject.send("JsonPost=" + JSON.stringify(SomeObject));
```

Why:

- `var JsonStr = {` creates an new real javascript object
- but this object can not used with `+` to concate it

Comment: You're attempting to encode the JSON as a key value in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. There are two problems that your attempt (1) You're not URL encoding the JSON so you might end up with errors the data. (2) The PHP is expecting the body to be raw JSON, not JSON embedded in application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Comment: *var JsonStr = { creates an new json object* — It does not. It creates a JavaScript object. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Quentin I attempting nothing. I followed the example from w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp and located an error in the version here and gave a tip to fix it. By the way send (w3schools.com) them an mail too.

Comment: "I attempting nothing" — You wrote some code. That code must be trying to do something.

Comment: "I followed the example from w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp" — The W3Schools example has different PHP. The change you made is incompatible with the PHP in the question.

Comment: @Quentin i am only human after all, seems that the OP was missing it too :-)

Comment: @Quentin _The PHP is expecting the body to be raw JSON_ is not right (in the context to the example here). But whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is this:

`var JsonStr = {JsonPost: JSON.stringify(SomeObject)};`

that is still a javasript object, you have to stringifly the whole thing

so this should wok:

```
var JsonStr = JSON.stringify({JsonPost: SomeObject});
RequestObject.send(JsonStr);
```

Comment: You're attempting to encode the JSON as a key value in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. There are two problems that your attempt (1) You're not URL encoding the JSON so you might end up with errors the data. (2) The PHP is expecting the body to be raw JSON, not JSON embedded in application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions — Why are you responding to my comment about zelding's code?